# Prove this diophantine equation $b^2=a^3+ac^4$have no integer solution,

Tags: diophantine-equations

show that this diophantine equation:
$$b^2=a^3+ac^4$$ has no soluton in non-zero integers

[Hint: first show that  $a$ must be a perfect square]

This problem is from this [PDF](http://www.gfsoso.com/?q=%20show%20%20that%20diophantine%20equation%20y%5E2%3Dx%5E3%2Bxz%5E4%20have%20%20no%20solutions%20in%20non-zero%20integers&pn=20)
[image]

I know this reslut$$a^4+b^4=c^2$$ have no solution in non-zero integers,
so this problem is key prove $a$ is perfect square.

My idea: since
$$b^2=a(a^2+c^4)$$
it is easy when $a=1,a^2+c^4=1+c^4=b^2$ have no integer nozero solution
so let 
$$a=bk_{1},a^2+c^4=bk_{2}?$$
then I can't

Comment: The right equations are $a=db_1^2,\ a^2+c^4=db_2^2,$ where $d=\gcd(a,a^2+c^4).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, $p$ is a prime, such that $p^u$ is the largest power dividing $a$ and the exponent is odd.

If $p$ does not divide $c$, the largest power $p^u$ dividing $a(a^2+c^4)$ is $p^u$, so the exponent is also odd.

If $p$ divides $c$, the $v$ in the largest power $p^v$ dividing $a^2+c^4$ is even. $p^{u+v}$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $a(a^2+c^4)$ , and $v+u$ is odd.

So, $a(a^2+c^4)$ cannot be a perfect square in any case.